# Migration: How can I map own product attributes and attributesets in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, csv, migration, attribute-set

I tried several migration ways for products from Magento 1 to Magento 2:

1. **Data-Migration-Tool by Magento**

   Including mapping but only for documents (tables) and fields (table columns). Another problem is it doesn't migrate utf-8.
2. **Migraton-Tool by Ubertheme**

   Nice tool! It doesn't completely overwrite all like Migration-Tool by Magento. But if I want to map Magento1-products to Magento2-products it doesn't know my own attributes and attribute sets I added to Magento2. So mapping doesn't work.
3. **own CSV Converter for Product Import in Admin**

   Because the tools don't seem to allow mapping to own attributes and attribute sets so I tried to build own CSV converter for Magento1-CSV files to compatible Magento2-CSV files for Product Import in *System->Import* in admin in Magento2. But I saw the CSV structure of Magento CSV-files is too unstructured to build a converter.

So anybody has an idea how can I map old magento1-products to own magento2-attributes and attribute sets?

I have over a thousand products to migrate so manual setting of attributes and attribute sets for every product isn't an option.